# Running multiline SQL query from C#

Tags: c#, sql

Currently I am running SQL queries like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SQLCONNECTION);
var databases = new List<string>();

using (var comm = new SqlCommand(SQLQUERY, conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            databases.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

But now I want to run an SQL Query like this (I have tested it in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
USE DATABASE
GO
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

How do I run a multiline query like this via the C# methods I've been using?

Comment: you can return multiple selects into a DataSet and it would access the datatables in a for loop so if you have 4 queries for example you would access the datatables as `DataSet.Tables[I]` which would be `DataSet.Tables[0], DataSet.Tables[1]....etc`

Comment: Why not change your connection string to point at the desired DB?

Comment: Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936665/sql-statement-in-multiple-lines-throwing-error already?

Comment: You could use a stored procedure instead of SQL strings in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DATABASE` name should be part of the connection string (`SQLCONNECTION`) see [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for examples.

You could build a [System.Text.StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to Append lines to the `SQLQUERY` string. Although building SQL in C# code like this is bad practice. Perhaps you could call a Stored Procedure instead?

Answer (score 0):

I read it into a string from a file:

```
string queryHolder = File.ReadAllText("FileNameGoesHere.txt");
using (var comm = new SqlCommand(queryHolder, conn))
```

That way you don't have to recompile code can just externally change

Comment: It is going to fail on the `GO`, you might want to address that.

Comment: Perfect! In your own words sir..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596876/go-statements-blowing-up-sql-execution-in-net

Comment: My rationale was answering "Multiline Query" not "Multiple Query". All this does is maintain formatting and creates easy alterations.